# How to connect 12v inverter to 24v two batteries system?

Tags: solar-power, electricity, electricity-generation, batteries

I have two 545 solar panels and 50 amps mppt charge controller feeding two 12v batteries and I have a 12v 1000 watt inverter, how do I connect the inverter to the batteries? Should I connect the inverter to one of the batteries? What do you suggest?

[image]

Comment: Looks like your charger will autodetect 12V or 24V, so you could connect the batteries in parallel and the the charger would work, then you could also connect the inverter directly to both batteries in parallel.

Comment: @lShaver yes but when using the batteries in parallel, it will only give me 650watts and the rest energy isn't harvested

Comment: What's the battery capacity, and how much power do you need?

Answer (score 2):

Buy a 24V inverter. There is really no other way if you want to continue using a 24 volt system. Connecting the 12V inverter to only one battery would imbalance that string.

I have a 24V to 12V DC-DC converter that gives 10 amperes, 120 watts. It cost 30 euros.

Your 1000 watt inverter due to inefficiency when giving 1000 watts takes probably more than 1100 watts in. So, nine of these 10 amperes 120 watts DC-DC converters wouldn't be enough, you would need ten. The cost: 300 euros.

The cheapest 1000 watt 24V inverter that I found costs 157 euros (modified square wave) or 180 euros (pure sine wave).

There's no comparison: converting that 24 volts into 12 volts and then converting to AC costs way more than directly converting to AC. Besides, every power conversion stage decreases efficiency.